# Extend djcelery taskmeta table

Tags: django, task, extend, djcelery

I'd like to extend the djcelery `taskmeta` table, for example I have a scheduled task that returns an integer value.

I'd like to add a field to store this value so I can graph this data along with the `date_done` field in the `taskmeta` table.

I tried to create a new model and making a foreignkey relationship with the `taskmeta` table, and inside my task add a row in this new table based on the `task_id`.

But I guess while the task executes, I won't be able to do, as I assume the `taskmeta` data has not been saved at this point, ie:

```
 if mover.request.id:
    try:
        task = TaskMeta.objects.get(task_id=mover.request.id)
                    extend_task_info = TaskExtended(task=task)
                    extend_task_info.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        logger.error('Task ID: %s not in the DB' % mover.request.id)
```

Addition of task code:

```
@task()
def mover():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
        path = root.split('/')
        for file in files:
            counter = process_file(os.path.join(root, file))

    if mover.request.id:
        try:
            tn = TaskMeta.objects.get(task_id=mover.request.id)
            extend_task_info = TaskExtended(task=task)
            extend_task_info.counter = counter
            extend_task_info.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            logger.error('Task ID: %s not in the DB' % mover.request.id)
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes the exception is raise, Task ID: eb381eda-6f2e-4c2c-8731-f290c02e4d2d not in the DB

Answer (score 1):

Use `task.AsyncResult(task_id)`. You can read more about it in the docs [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-task-if-i-have-the-id-that-points-there).

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure I totally understand. This would return an AsyncResult, no? How would this help me save extended info into the taskmeta table or extend to another while I'm in the task? Would you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @JoeLones - Sure. Using `.AsyncResult()` gives you access to the task while it's running. Which is good in your case because you are trying to extend it before it exists, or not finished, hence the `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: I amended my op and added my task code, still not sure I grasp it. In the code above wouldn't the exception always get trigger. Isn't the taskmeta data save once the task ends?

Comment: Correct, it would always raise the exception because the task is not saved until it completes. `.AsyncResult()` allows you to access the task, well asynchronously, while it's running.

Comment: Right, so how would I save the TaskExtended info if I don't have an instance of the TaskMeta I refer to via the foreign key? It's not possible then?

Comment: `.AsyncResult()` returns the instance of the running task. Maybe it would be helpful if you posted your `TaskExtended()` class.